# Easy shell solution to execute a command for each line of stdout

Tags: shell

This should be an absurdly easy task: I want to take each line of the stdout of any old command, and use each to execute another command with it as an argument.

For example:

ls | grep foo | applycommand 'mv %s bar/'

Where this would take everything matching "*foo*" and move it to the bar/ directory.

(I feel a bit embarrassed asking for what is probably a ridiculously obvious solution.)

Comment: In case your filenames have spaces in them: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That program is called `xargs`.

```
ls | grep foo | xargs -I %s mv %s bar/
```

Comment: xargs also lets you insert arguments in the middle of the command by specifying a substitution string. i.e. `xargs -I FILE mv FILE bar/`

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, I learnt something new! Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: also mv has a --target option. so just: | xargs mv --target=bar/

Comment: @pixelbeat: Thanks! I was trying to model my answer after what the OP wanted (with `%s` and all), but obviously in this case, your solution is even better.

Comment: this doesn't execute a command for each line of stdin. It just bundles it together in one shot. The OP mentions this case only as an example. :\

Comment: @Karthick Correct, the question title is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13), so I solved the _real_ problem with my answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
ls | grep foo | while read FILE; do mv "$FILE" bar/; done
```

This particular operation could be done more simply, though:

```
mv *foo* bar/
```

Or for a recursive solution:

```
find -name '*foo*' -exec mv {} bar/ \;
```

In the `find` command `{}` will be replaced by the list of files that match.

Comment: Almost right: when doing `-exec ... +`, the `{}` must immediately precede the `+`. You can use the `;` form though: `-exec mv {} bar/ ';'`.

Answer (score 0):

for your case, do it simply like this.

```
for file in *foo*
do
   if [ -f "$file" ];then
      mv "$file" /destination
   fi
done
```

OR just mv it if you don't care about directories or files

```
mv *foo* /destination
```