# How to apply shell command to each line of a command output?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have some output from a command (such as `ls -1`):

```
a
b
c
d
e
...
```

I want to apply a command (say `echo`) to each one, in turn. E.g.

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
echo d
echo e
...
```

What's the easiest way to do that in bash?

Comment: `ls -1` may be an example here but it is important to remember that it is not good to parse the output of `ls`.  See: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 333, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use `xargs`. In your case:

```
ls -1 | xargs -L1 echo
```

The `-L` flag ensures the input is read properly. From the man page of `xargs`:

```
-L number
    Call utility for every number non-empty lines read. 
    A line ending with a space continues to the next non-empty line. [...]
```

Comment: `ls` automatically does `-1` in a pipe.

Comment: @Dennis, doesn't look like it: `ls | xargs -L2 echo` and `ls -1 | xargs -L2 echo` give two different outputs. The former being all on one line.

Comment: @Alex: I get the same output.

Comment: `xargs` can run only executable files not shell functions or shell built-in commands. For the former the best solution is probably the one with `read` in a loop.

Comment: Depending on the file names, and the command (something that is not `echo`), you might need to say `ls -1 -Q | xargs -L1 command`

Comment: This would behave very badly with unusual/surprising names. Try names with spaces or quotes.

Comment: Perf note: the `while` solution is way faster than this one though.

Comment: `xargs -L1` has a shortcut: `xargs -l`

Comment: `ls` behaves like `ls -1` and prints one file name per line when it senses that the output is not connected to a terminal, as in the case of a pipeline `ls | ...` or `ls > file`.

Comment: I wish this answer included an explanation of what `-L1` is for.

Comment: **-L, --max-lines=MAX-LINES**  
use at most MAX-LINES non-blank input lines per command line.

- Meaning that xargs with -L1 will execute a command _consuming_ a single line at each time.

Comment: Doesn't work with filenames that have whitespace in them, tries and runs the command on each segment of the filename.

Comment: @balupton That was pointed out five years ago. You'd probably have to use some combination of `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, but including spaces in filenames is going to break so many things that you should really just not do it

Comment: I use xargs but didn't know -L1 was present.. it opens up a lot more options to me... thanks

Comment: Btw, this is not ideal, as `xargs` doesn’t actually call bash’s `echo` but `/usr/bin/echo`, giving the illusion of being able to call script functions, while spawning a slow new process for each call.

Answer (score 274):

You can use a basic prepend operation on each line:

```
ls -1 | while read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

Or you can pipe the output to sed for more complex operations:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/echo \1/'
```

Comment: The sed command doesn't seem to work: `sh: cho: not found a sh: cho: not found` Looks like it's taking the `e` in echo to be a sed command or something.

Comment: +1 for the `while` loop. `cmd1 | while read line; do cmd2 $line; done`. Or `while read line; do cmd2 $line; done < <(cmd1)` which doesn't create a subshell. This is the simplified version of your `sed` command: `sed 's/.*/echo &/'`

Comment: @Alex: change the double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't the quotes -- I just missed the `s` for substitution. But this just prints out lines like `echo foo`, etc. Not executing the `echo`.

Comment: @Alex: That is correct the lines are not executed.  The while example is much more flexible and will simply execute the commands (which is why I put "echo echo ..." so echo would actually be displayed)

Comment: Quote the `"$line"` in the while loop, in order to avoid word splitting.

Comment: Try using `read -r line` to prevent `read` messing with escaped characters. For example `echo '"a \"nested\" quote"' | while read line; do echo "$line"; done` gives `"a "nested" quote"`, which has lost its escaping. If we do `echo '"a \"nested\" quote"' | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done` we get `"a \"nested\" quote"` as expected. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read

Comment: @Trey, ...look at what happens with a filename with a tab character or a run of spaces right now -- you'll see them replaced with a single space. Or a file named `-n` may simply have no output at all. Or a file named `*` could be replaced with all the other files in the directory, printing the others twice and leaving it out. `printf '%s\n' "$line"` would be much more reliable.

Comment: Moreover, `ls -1` isn't guaranteed to represent names accurately; names with newline literals, for instance, *simply can't* be represented accurately in a newline-delimited stream. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs goes into more pitfalls.

Answer (score 20):

```
for s in `cmd`; do echo $s; done
```

If cmd has a large output:

```
cmd | xargs -L1 echo
```

Comment: if `cmd` has spaces in its output, the first one will fail.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls entry #1

Comment: If the output contains single quotes the xargs one will not work correctly

Answer (score 12):

You can use a [for loop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/):

```
for file in * ; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Note that if the command in question accepts multiple arguments, then using [xargs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html) is almost always more efficient as it only has to spawn the utility in question once instead of multiple times.

Comment: It's worth describing the proper/safe use of xargs, ie. `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 ...` -- otherwise, it's quite unsafe with filenames with whitespace, quotes, etc.

Answer (score 12):

A solution that works with filenames that have spaces in them, is:

```
ls -1 | xargs -I %s echo %s
```

The following is equivalent, but has a clearer divide between the precursor and what you actually want to do:

```
ls -1 | xargs -I %s -- echo %s
```

Where `echo` is whatever it is you want to run, and the subsequent `%s` is the filename.

Thanks to [Chris Jester-Young](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376278/130638) on a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2376271/130638).

Answer (score 11):

You actually *can* use sed to do it, provided it is GNU sed.

```
... | sed 's/match/command \0/e'
```

How it works:

1. Substitute match with command match
2. **On substitution** execute command
3. Replace substituted line with command output.

Comment: Fantastic. I forgot to put the  **e** command at the end, but did so after seeing your reply and it worked.  I was trying to append a random ID between 1000 and 15000, when SED matches a line.

  `cat /logs/lfa/Modified.trace.log.20150904.pw | sed -r 's/^(.*)(\|006\|00032\|)(.*)$/echo "\1\2\3 - ID \`shuf -i 999-14999 -n 1\`"/e' `

Answer (score 3):

xargs fails with with backslashes, quotes. It needs to be something like

```
ls -1 |tr \\n \\0 |xargs -0 -iTHIS echo "THIS is a file."
```

xargs -0 option:

> ```
> -0, --null
>           Input  items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are
>           not special (every character is taken literally).  Disables the end of file string, which is treated  like
>           any  other argument.  Useful when input items might contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.  The
>           GNU find -print0 option produces input suitable for this mode.
> ```

`ls -1` terminates the items with newline characters, so `tr` translates them into null characters.

This approach is about 50 times slower than iterating manually with `for ...` (see *Michael Aaron Safyan*s answer) (3.55s vs. 0.066s). But for other input commands like locate, find, reading from a file (`tr \\n \\0 <file`) or similar, you have to work with `xargs` like this.

Comment: On macOS: `xargs: illegal option -- i`

Comment: @balupton the portable option is `| xargs-s -0 -I something echo "something is my file"`

Answer (score 3):

i like to use gawk for running multiple commands on a list, for instance

```
ls -l | gawk '{system("/path/to/cmd.sh "$1)}'
```

however the escaping of the escapable characters can get a little hairy.

Answer (score 1):

Better result for me:

```
ls -1 | xargs -L1 -d "\n" CMD
```

Comment: Better, but not perfect. `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 command` will handle cases where the output of `ls -1` is ambiguous; use `-printf '%P\0'` rather than `-print0` if you don't want a leading `./` on each.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [Execute a command once per line of piped input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input) it seems.

I don’t know if it’s appropriate to post an adapted version of the same answer, since it’s the same question, like everyone else did. I’d prefer to merge the questions (any admin reading this?).

But until then, here we go:

What you are asking for is known as a *functor*. A mapping function.

Since `echo` isn’t a particularly sensible function to apply things to, since things that go in a pipe are already echoed without that pipe, I’ll use the custom function `bla()` here.

I also adapted the answer for your `ls -1` case.

---

This should work for *everything*,

- **including self-defined functions** (which xargs can’t do directly),
- **without spawning any additional processes** (like xargs does), and
- **without removing spaces** (which read otherwise does!).

Note the `IFS=` and `-r`, not included in any other answer:

```bash
mapp() { while IFS= read -r line; do "$1" "$line"; done; }
```

Here’s an example usage:

```bash
$ bla() { echo "  bla: $1"; }
$ ls -1 | mapp bla 
  bla: a
  bla: b
  bla: c
  …
```

---

For alternative versions and other variants, see my answer to the other question.