# grep many different strings

Tags: grep

I have a file `strings.txt` containing 100 strings, each on a line

```
string1
string2
...
string100
```

For each of those strings, I want to find all the lines in `file_to_look.txt` that contain that string. Now, I could run `grep` 100 times like `grep string1 file_to_look.txt`, then `grep string2 file_to_look.txt`, etc., but that would take a lot of typing time for me.

Is there a way that I don't have to do so much typing?

EDIT: Solutions that go through `file_to_look.txt` only 1 time instead of 100 times would be great, since my `file_to_look.txt` is quite large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-f` is for passing (GNU) grep a pattern file.

```
grep -f strings.txt file_to_look.txt
```

Comment: This seems like the most elegant way to do it; +1

Comment: Does it go through the input file 1 time or 100 times?

Comment: It reads the pattern file once, then scans the input file once, so just 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do grep "$line" file_to_look.txt; done < strings.txt
```

That does exactly what you asked for. Substitute ";" for newlines as you see fit.

xargs is the other option people will suggest. My suggestion is to generally look for another alternative first, as xarg has a bunch of gotchas which can make things go very wrong.

[Greg's bash wiki on xargs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk%3a_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually xargs is used for repeating commands with multiple values:

```
xargs -I{} grep {} file_to_look.txt < strings.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `while read`, like this:

```
cat strings.txt | while read line ; do grep "$line" file_to_look.txt ; done
```

For more alternative ways take a look at:

- [How to apply shell command to each line of a command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711001/how-to-apply-shell-command-to-each-line-of-a-command-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name=string.txt
file_to_look=file_to_look.txt
patterns=$(tr '\n' '|' $filename)
patterns=${patterns%?} # remove the last |
grep -E $patterns $file_to_look
```

This rounds up all of your search patterns together and hands it off to `grep` in one go with the `-E` option, so `grep` only has to parse through `file_to_look.txt` once, instead of a 100 times.