# How to rewrite while loop in bash script to prevent create temp file?

Tags: bash

I think generate temp file may slower and if user press **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>** the temp file will become garbage.

Here is my original code

```
for f in bin/* ; do
  ldd $f 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
done | sort -u | grep -v -e '^not$' -e 'ld-linux' > list.1
while read soname ; do
  process_so_name $soname
done < list.1
```

Is it possible to remove the temp file list.1?

Comment: I think you mean to ask "Can I rewrite this code so it doesn't use a temp file on disk", right?

Comment: I believe the key to your problem is the `xargs` command; see [this earlier SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711001/how-to-apply-shell-command-to-each-line-of-a-command-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it without a temp file. Pipe the result of the last grep into the while.

You can hook into SIGINT to detect Ctrl+C, but why worry if you don't need to? You still won't be able to hook into SIGKILL.

```
for f in bin/* ; do
  ldd $f 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
done | sort -u | grep -v -e '^not$' -e 'ld-linux' | while read soname ; do
  process_so_name $soname
done
```

You can make this look more recognizable by placing the loops in functions (you can do this in a script file or right in the shell):

```
step_1() {
  for f in bin/* ; do
    ldd $f 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
  done
}

step_2() {
  while read soname ; do
    process_so_name $soname
  done
}

step_1 | grep -v -e '^not$' -e 'ld-linux' | step_2
```

To hook into SIGINT, do something like this:

```
trap "echo SIGINT; rm -f tempfile; exit -1" INT
```

To hook into SIGTERM (see comments underneath), do this:

```
trap "echo SIGTERM; rm -f tempfile; exit -1" EXIT
```

Comment: you can also trap `EXIT` to ensure that your trap runs on SIGTERM, an 'exit' command, aborts due to `set -e` and other exit conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @MihaiDanila I like all three answers, but your answer provide more things for learn.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MihaiDanila 's correct answer,

If you wan't to reuse some statistic value in your *main* loop, you have to re-order your script and use *Process Substitution*

```
total=0
processed=0
while read soname ; do
  ((total=total+1))
  process_so_name $soname && ((processed=processed+1))
done < <(
    for f in bin/* ; do
      ldd $f 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
    done |
      sort -u |
      grep -v -e '^not$' -e 'ld-linux'
)
printf "Total file %d, processed ok: %d, last filename: '%s'" \
    $total $processed $soname
```

Syntax using pipe, like `... grep -v | while read soname` will do a *fork* after pipe, so the environment of *main loop* will be dropped at end.

See: `man -Len -Pless\ -i\ +/^\\\ *process\\\ substitution$ bash`

Answer (score 1):

like @M

another way without tempfile

```
function func_name(){
for f in bin/* ; do
ldd $f 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
done | sort -u | grep -v -e '^not$' -e 'ld-linux'
}

while read soname ; do
process_so_name $soname
done < <(func_name)
```

test

```
function func_name2(){
echo 1
echo 2
}

while read soname ; do
echo $soname
done < <(func_name2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
for f in bin/* ; do
  ldd $f 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
done | sort -u | grep -v -e '^not$' -e 'ld-linux' | xargs -n 1 process_so_name
```

Comment: Compact, but harder to adapt to files with spaces in their names than the more verbose `while`.

Comment: to match up with the original code, use the `-n 1` option for xargs

Comment: @MihaiDanila, to handle files with spaces, use `xargs -I {} process_so_name {}`

Comment: @glennjackmanCorrect. I've also seen a lot in the xargs man page about how to cause the command upstream of xargs to use a `\0` to delimit records in order to allow xargs to find the same via `-0`. Our asker is safe from that complication due to his precise requirement of calling with one argument at a time, but not with `xargs -n 1`.

Comment: I do love the xargs, that is arguably the most important for the OP to learn here. Hmm, has it been eight years? :)