# Loop through CURL results

Tags: bash, curl

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $('curl -s https://scans.io/data/rapid7/sonar.http/20141209-http.gz | zcat | head -n 1000 | dap json + select vhost + lines');
do
    echo "$line\n"
done
```

For which I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Loop through a dynamically growing list of results from the scans.io curl
2. Output the line which I then propose to pass to PHP to store and process

However I'm getting `syntax error near unexpected token`$'\r''` but am not a BASH expert to know what I need to tweak.

Comment: remove the single quotes

Comment: Unless you are doing more than just echoing the line in the body, you don't need the loop at all, just pipe the output of `dap` directly to PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Process-Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution?highlight=%28Process%29%7C%28substitution%29), with a *while-loop*, see [why using for-loop for command output parsing is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). The unsetting of `IFS` and  `read` with the `-r` flag  does not allow backslashes to escape any characters and treat strings "as-is".

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(curl -s https://scans.io/data/rapid7/sonar.http/20141209-http.gz | zcat | head -n 1000 | dap json + select vhost + lines)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found I could also do it but by piping the command as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711001

Comment: @Antony: _Always_ use tools/suggestions available from the native shell, rather than depending on third party tools for the reasons of portability. The approach I suggested is more reliable.

Comment: With piping being the third party element?

Comment: @Antony: `pipe` is a communication medium which is a kernel built-in, I meant the usage of `xargs`

Comment: Ah sorry - was using the 2nd answer. Also will happily mark your answer but unfortunately got `dap.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
dap.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'`.

Comment: @Antony: Are you using `cygwin`, if so can you do `dos2unix dap.sh` to remove Windows `CRLF` endings? and run the script again?