# follow logfile with tail and exec on event

Tags: sh, ash

i wonder if there is a more simplyfied way to run the tail -f or -F on a logfile and execute a command each time a special keyword is mentioned.

this is my working solution so far, but i don't like it for following reasons:

- i have to write new lines for each match to log file to avoid endless loop
- tail does not follow exactly the log, it could miss some lines while the command is executed
- i am not aware about CPU usage because of high frequency

example:

```
#!/sbin/sh
while [ 1 ]
  do
    tail -n1 logfile.log | grep "some triggering text" && mount -v $stuff >> logfile.log
done
```

i tried the following but grep won't give return code until the pipe break

```
#!/sbin/sh
tail -f -n1 logfile.log | grep "some triggering text" && mount $stuff
```

i am running a script on android which is limited to
busybox ash

edit:
the problem is related to grep. grep won't give return code until the last line. what i need is return code for each line. maybe kind of a --follow option for grep, or sed, awk, or a user defined function which works with tail --follow

Comment: Use `grep` with `--line-buffered`

Comment: i think i found a solution `tail -f -n1 logfile.log | while [ 1 ]; do grep -m1 "text" && mount $stuff; done`

Comment: still using this ugly code, it render device unresponsible on growing logfile :(

Comment: write a small C/C++ program according to to your needs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21727749 might work, will try